# Getting checkbox checked or not in a array in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box0" name="mark_box[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box1" name="mark_box[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box2" name="mark_box[]">
```

I want to get the checked and not checked check boxes in a array. Please refer the sample output array below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 //mark_box0 is checked
    [1] => 0 //mark_box1 is not checked
    [2] => 1 //mark_box2 is checked
)
```

I tried some code but not working correctly

```
var is_checked = $("input[name='mark_box[]']").map(function(){return this.value;}).get();
```

above code returns below array whenever checked or not

```
Array
(
    [0] => on
    [1] => on
    [2] => on
)
```

---

```
var is_checked = $("input[name=mark_box]:checked").map(function() {
     return this.value;
 }).get().join(","));  // returns empty array
```

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` attribute return value of input. You should use `checked` that return status of checkbox.

```
var is_checked = $("input[name='mark_box[]']").map(function(){
  return this.checked ? 1 : 0;
}).get();
```

```js
var is_checked = $("input[name='mark_box[]']").map(function(){
  return this.checked ? 1 : 0;
}).get(); 
console.log(is_checked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked id="mark_box0" name="mark_box[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box1" name="mark_box[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box2" name="mark_box[]">
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are using is correct but you are getting the value which will remain same at every state. You have to check that the checkbox is checked or not. Here is the code:

```
var is_checked = $("input[name='mark_box[]']").map(function(){
       return $(this).attr("checked");
}).get();
```

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Depending on the jQuery version `prop("checked")` may be preferable to `attr("checked")`

Comment: @apokryfos I agree with you. I also thinking that there should be `prop` function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for `checked` and not `value`

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  var checkedArray = $("input[name='mark_box[]']").map(function() {
    return this.checked;
  }).get();
  console.log(checkedArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box0" name="mark_box[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box1" name="mark_box[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box2" name="mark_box[]">
<button class='button'>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

Instead of using

```
var is_checked = $("input[name=mark_box]:checked").map(function() {
     return this.value;
 }).get().join(","));  // returns empty array
```

Use

```
var is_checked = $("input['name=mark_box[]']:checked").map(function() {
     return this.value;
 }).get().join(","));  // returns empty array
```

(Note the `[]`).

With the `:checked` selector, you don't need to loop all the inputs. It will give you all the checked elements automatically.

So `$("input[name='mark_box[]']:checked")` returns all the checked checkboxes.

```js
$(function() {
  var checkedArr = $("input[name='mark_box[]']:checked");
  
  /*for the output:*/
  var print = $("input[name='mark_box[]']:checked").map(function() { 
   return $(this).attr('id');}).get().join(",");
  console.log( print );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box0" name="mark_box[]" />
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box1" name="mark_box[]" checked />
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box2" name="mark_box[]" />
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box3" name="mark_box[]" checked />
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box4" name="mark_box[]" checked />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like below

```js
function getValues(){
var array = [];
$("input:checkbox[name='mark_box[]']").each(function(){
    array.push($(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : 0);
});
console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box0" name="mark_box[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box1" name="mark_box[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="mark_box2" name="mark_box[]">

<button type="button" onclick="getValues()">Run</button>
```